# Integer solutions on summation of primes powers

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

Let $\alpha$ be any prime number and $n_1\ge n_2\ge n_3$, $k_1\ge k_2\ge k_3$. If $\alpha^{n_1}+\alpha^{n_3}+\alpha^{n_3}=\alpha^{k_1}+\alpha^{k_2}+\alpha^{k_3},$ does this implies $n_1=k_1,n_2=k_2,n_3=k_3$?

Comment: No, not necessarily. It's possible that $n_1=k_2$, $n_2=k_3$, and $n_3=k_1$.

But I know what you mean. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter-example:

$2^3+2^3+2^3=2^4+2^2+2^2$

Comment: If n1, n2, n3 are different then is it possible?

Comment: Let me put it this way: if $\forall n, 0\le d_n < \alpha$ and $\forall n, 0\le k_n < \alpha$ then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n\alpha^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty k_n \alpha^n$$ implies $\forall n, d_n = k_n$. So, in this case, you have $d_{n_1} = k_{n_1} = 1$, $d_{n_2} = k_{n_2} = 1$, and $d_{n_3} = k_{n_3} = 1$ and $d_n=0$ for all other $n$. So, if $n_1>n_2>n_3$, then yes, it is always true. In fact, if $\alpha > 2$, it is still always true even if some of the $n_i$'s are equal.